# TypeError Traceback (most recent call last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13360\2773595183.pyetudents_data.values()))

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to use filter function and store the result in list

```
students_data = {1:['Sam', 15] , 2:['Rob',18], 3:['Kyle', 16], 4:['Cornor',19], 5:['Trump',20]}

list1 = list(filter(lambda x : x[1] > 18, students_data.values()))
```

but it showing this result

```
<filter at 0x230f41616a0>
```

but i want output

```
4:['Cornor',19], 5:['Trump',20]
```

Comment: Your statement returns `[['Cornor', 19], ['Trump', 20]]`, which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

you want to get in result the keys (4, 5), but in the filter you use `students_data.values()` which returns only values

```
students_data = {1: ['Sam', 15], 2: ['Rob', 18], 3: ['Kyle', 16], 4: ['Cornor', 19], 5: ['Trump', 20]}
result = dict(filter(lambda x : x[1][1] > 18, list(students_data.items())))
```

here `result` equals `{4: ['Cornor', 19], 5: ['Trump', 20]}`
but i'm not sure you need dict or list

so if u need the list:

```
result = list(filter(lambda x : x[1][1] > 18, list(students_data.items())))
```

Comment: i used your solution but i give me same error

Comment: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_13360\3630066508.py in <module>
----> 1 result = list(filter(lambda x : x[1][1] > 18, list(students_data.items())))

TypeError: 'filter' object is not callable

Comment: send me the whole python module... I guess you have overwritten `filter`